# Can a subclass use same methods, but with different variable types? and how? (JAVA)

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I created a class for `BinarySearchTree` and a class for `BinarySearchTreeNode`.  Now I am creating a subclass for `BinarySearchTree`, is there any way I can use all the same methods but with a subclass node?  Therefore all methods would be the same as the original class, but using a subclass of my node for everything?  how?

Answer (score 3):

You could have the tree use a generic type of node, and further specify it when you inherit from it:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends BinarySearchTreeNode> {
    // Just an example
    public void add(T node) {
        // Code...
    }
}

public class SpecialBinarySearchTree extends BinarySearchTree<SpecialBinarySearchNode> {
    // Just an example
    @Override
    public void add(SpecialBinarySearchNode node) {
        // Code...
    }
}
```